# store azure table diagonistics data into sql server database

Tags: c#, azure, cloud

i am new to windows azure. but here is what i need to do. i need to read diagonistics data from any app deployed in windows azure, i mean log file and store them in sql server and then generate reports from it (will have to use ssrs). i really dont know how to do it.

i tried this link but i was unable to follow it [Reporting on Diagnostics Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh394141.aspx)

i need help out here. i dont know how to write the connection string from the worker role to read data and then save it in the local sql server database.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article is a great place to start since it covers everything you should do. Did you know you can download the sample application described in the article? You can download it from the 'old' [code.msdn.com site](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mag201109Cloudy/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5721).

In this sample application you'll see that the connection string is stored in the app.config of the worker role. As an alternative, you can also store the connection string in the Service  Configuration (double click the Worker Role in the Azure project, go to settings and add the connection string here):

[image]

Then when initializing your data context, you'll need to read that value from the ServiceConfiguration:

```
PerfDataEntities pde = new PerfDataEntities(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("PerfDataEntities"));
```

Doing this will allow you to have 1 connection string per environment (ie: when you're developing locally, running in 'beta', in production, ...).

Comment: hey thanks. I had read the blog earlier but the code link given on the blog page was not working. Thanks a lot for the code.